# file_get_contents with get_template_part

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to grab all contents of a WordPress template and look for some data in it. We were able to do that with

```
$content = file_get_contents( locate_template( $template_name ) );
```

But we see commented out PHP for get_template_part like this

```
<section id="banner" class="section pm-0">
    <!--?php get_template_part( $template-part-name ); ?-->
</section>
```

So we have content only for the template and all other content within the template part does not get included and we have incomplete content

Comment: ___Solve this___ And what would a solution look like please

Comment: If you mean can you remove all the HTML comments then Yes, but you will have to write something to do it

Comment: No, we don't want just want to remove the comments we need to include the content within the template part as well. There is data within the template part which we cannot access